# Create an Envelope of the following XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml, xmldocument

I am struggling with this situations for a while!! and i really hope i can get some help from you.

in a method i am receiving this XML as a string :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="no"?>
<VC_001_CreateDocument>
  <VCRequest>
    <Header>
      <OrganisationData>
        <ClientId />
        <UserId />
        <Pass />
      </OrganisationData>
      <Article>
        <OutcomeSource>ERP</OutcomeSource>
        <ArticleNumber>6034967-Sample</ArticleNumber>
        <ProductNumbers>
          <ProductNumber Type="GTIN" Level="PRI" />
        </ProductNumbers>
        <Forecast />
        <ERPStatus>APP</ERPStatus>
        <SerialisationFlag />
        <CSDBArticleNumber>6034967-Sample</CSDBArticleNumber>
        <ArticleDescription>Rose</ArticleDescription>
        <WorkflowId />
        <CommonName />
        <PharmaceuticalForm />
        <Strength />
        <PackageWeight />
        <PackageSize />
        <PackageType />
        <GS1GLN />
        <GS1CompanyPrefix />
        <Customer>
          <CustomerId />
          <CustomerErpNumber />
        </Customer>
        <ShelfLife />
        <Region />
        <ProductionSites>
          <ProductionSite>
            <ProductionSiteId />
            <ProductionSiteErpNumber />
          </ProductionSite>
        </ProductionSites>
        <GenericArticleField01 />
        <GenericArticleField02 />
        <GenericArticleField03 />
        <GenericArticleField04 />
        <GenericArticleField05 />
        <RequiredFields>
          <RequiredField Name="" />
        </RequiredFields>
        <Comment />
        <Checked />
        <TargetMarkets>
          <TargetMarket>
            <GS1NHRN />
            <GenericFields Type="" Language="" />
            <Mah />
            <Wholesaler />
          </TargetMarket>
        </TargetMarkets>
        <VerificationSystem />
        <Email />
        <FixData />
        <StartValueInitial />
        <SubPools>
          <SubPool>
            <AggregationLevel />
            <PoolIdentProductNumber />
            <QuantityPerLevel />
            <IncompletePackagingRule />
            <QuantityOfLayer />
            <GenerationPattern />
            <PostProductionSerialNumberAssignment />
            <PrePrinting />
            <Factor />
            <Threshold />
            <SerialNumberType />
            <ExtensionDigit />
            <SerialNumberSource />
            <DeliveranceInformation>
              <MinimumValue />
              <PercentualAmount />
            </DeliveranceInformation>
          </SubPool>
        </SubPools>
        <Report>
          <ReportExternal />
          <ReportVerificationSystem />
        </Report>
      </Article>
    </Header>
  </VCRequest>
</VC_001_CreateDocument>
```

to transform in an Envelope to use in my SOAP Request exactly like this: reading the node values of course if they have!

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:csdb="http://site.de/csdb">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <csdb:VC_001_CreateDocument>
      <csdb:VARequest>
        <csdb:Header>
          <csdb:OrganisationData>
            <csdb:ClientId>EDP</csdb:ClientId>
            <csdb:UserId>webservice</csdb:UserId>
            <csdb:Pass>!password*</csdb:Pass>
          </csdb:OrganisationData>
        </csdb:Header>
        <csdb:Article>
          <csdb:OutcomeSource>ERP</csdb:OutcomeSource>
          <csdb:ArticleNumber>6034967-Sample</csdb:ArticleNumber>
          <csdb:ProductNumbers>
            <csdb:ProductNumber type="GTIN" level="PRI"></csdb:ProductNumber>
          </csdb:ProductNumbers>
          <csdb:Forecast></csdb:Forecast>
          <csdb:ERPStatus></csdb:ERPStatus>
          <csdb:SerialisationFlag></csdb:SerialisationFlag>
          <csdb:CSDBArticleNumber>6034967-AMOSTRA</csdb:CSDBArticleNumber>
          <csdb:ArticleDescription>PINOX ROSA</csdb:ArticleDescription>
          <csdb:WorkflowId></csdb:WorkflowId>
          <csdb:CommonName></csdb:CommonName>
          <csdb:PharmaceuticalForm></csdb:PharmaceuticalForm>
          <csdb:Strength></csdb:Strength>
          <csdb:PackageWeight></csdb:PackageWeight>
          <csdb:PackageSize></csdb:PackageSize>
          <csdb:PackageType></csdb:PackageType>
          <csdb:GS1GLN></csdb:GS1GLN>
          <csdb:GS1CompanyPrefix></csdb:GS1CompanyPrefix>
          <csdb:Customer>
            <csdb:Customer></csdb:Customer>
            <csdb:CustomerId></csdb:CustomerId>
            <csdb:CustomerErpNumber></csdb:CustomerErpNumber>
          </csdb:Customer>>
          <csdb:ShelfLife></csdb:ShelfLife>
          <csdb:Region></csdb:Region>
          <csdb:ProductionSites>
            <csdb:ProductionSite>
              <csdb:ProductionSiteId></csdb:ProductionSiteId>
              <csdb:ProductionSiteErpNumber></csdb:ProductionSiteErpNumber>
            </csdb:ProductionSite>
          </csdb:ProductionSites>
          <csdb:GenericArticleField01></csdb:GenericArticleField01>
          <csdb:GenericArticleField02></csdb:GenericArticleField02>
          <csdb:GenericArticleField03></csdb:GenericArticleField03>
          <csdb:GenericArticleField04></csdb:GenericArticleField04>
          <csdb:GenericArticleField05></csdb:GenericArticleField05>
          <csdb:RequiredFields>
            <csdb:RequiredField name="?"></csdb:RequiredField>
          </csdb:RequiredFields>
          <csdb:Comment></csdb:Comment>
          <csdb:Checked></csdb:Checked>
          <csdb:GS1NHRN GS1NHRNNational="?"></csdb:GS1NHRN>
          <csdb:TargetMarkets>
            <csdb:TargetMarket targetMarket="?">
              <csdb:GS1NHRN GS1NHRNNational="?"></csdb:GS1NHRN>
              <csdb:GenericFields type="?" language="?"></csdb:GenericFields>
              <csdb:Mah></csdb:Mah>
              <csdb:Wholesaler></csdb:Wholesaler>
            </csdb:TargetMarket>
          </csdb:TargetMarkets>
          <csdb:Verificationsystem></csdb:Verificationsystem>
          <csdb:Email></csdb:Email>
          <csdb:FixData></csdb:FixData>
          <csdb:StartValueInitial></csdb:StartValueInitial>
          <csdb:Subpools>
            <csdb:Subpool>
              <csdb:AggregationLevel></csdb:AggregationLevel>
              <csdb:PoolIdentProductNumber type="?"></csdb:PoolIdentProductNumber>
              <csdb:QuantityPerLevel></csdb:QuantityPerLevel>
              <csdb:IncompletePackagingRule></csdb:IncompletePackagingRule>
              <csdb:QuantityOfLayer></csdb:QuantityOfLayer>
              <csdb:GenerationPattern></csdb:GenerationPattern>
              <csdb:PostProductionSerialNumberAssignment></csdb:PostProductionSerialNumberAssignment>
              <csdb:PrePrinting></csdb:PrePrinting>
              <csdb:Factor></csdb:Factor>
              <csdb:Threshold></csdb:Threshold>
              <csdb:SerialNumberType></csdb:SerialNumberType>
              <csdb:ExtensionDigit></csdb:ExtensionDigit>
              <csdb:SerialNumberSource></csdb:SerialNumberSource>
              <csdb:DeliveranceInformation>
                <csdb:MinimumValue></csdb:MinimumValue>
                <csdb:PercentualAmount></csdb:PercentualAmount>
              </csdb:DeliveranceInformation>
            </csdb:Subpool>
          </csdb:Subpools>
          <csdb:Report>
            <csdb:ReportExternal></csdb:ReportExternal>
            <csdb:ReportVerificationSystem></csdb:ReportVerificationSystem>
          </csdb:Report>
        </csdb:Article>
      </csdb:VCRequest>
    </csdb:VC_001_CreateDocument>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

THis is exactly the XML that i receive and that's the envelope that i will have to create (Request generated by SOAPUI),the nodes will have dynamic Values of course, those parameteres were just an example.
i assume this is the easiest way since i can't "add service reference" because i am trying to develop a DLL where the webservices will be nested. There's no web.config where this DLL is going to be installed.
Thank you soo much for helping me with the logic for this problem that is driving me crazy

Answer (score 0):

Using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            reader.ReadLine(); // skip the utf-16 in header that Net Library doesn't accept
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);

            string soapHeader = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:csdb=\"http://site.de/csdb\">" +
                "<soapenv:Header/>" +
                "<soapenv:Body>" +
                "</soapenv:Body>" +
                "</soapenv:Envelope>";

            XElement soap = XElement.Parse(soapHeader);
            XNamespace nsCsdb = soap.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("csdb");
            XNamespace nsSoapenv = soap.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("soapenv");
            XElement body = soap.Descendants(nsSoapenv + "Body").FirstOrDefault();

            body.Add(doc.Root);
            foreach (XElement child in body.Descendants())
            {
                child.Name = nsCsdb.GetName(child.Name.LocalName);
                List<XAttribute> atList = child.Attributes().ToList();
                child.Attributes().Remove();
                foreach (XAttribute at in atList)
                    child.Add(new XAttribute(nsCsdb.GetName(at.Name.LocalName), at.Value));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello my friend! this seems to work i will test it asap and i will give you the feedback, but why the body.Add(doc.Root); ?? are u adding the root element to the body? but the root element is not <soapenv:Envelope?. If i want to write that XML to a new folder what line of code should i use? is it possible to create an XML inside my project with the output result? if not in some other folder. In case i receive a String as my XML and i won't be able to execute reader.ReadLine(); // to skip the utf-16 in header that Net Library doesn't accept, how can i skip that line?

Comment: doc is a XDocument and the body.Add needs a XElement.  Using doc.Root get the XElement from the XDocument.  Not sure I understand all you questions.   XElement has a save method : soap.Save(stream).  You can use a MemoryStream to use the xml inside you app.  Or simply convert to the string : string soapStr = soap.ToString();  When you xml is a string then use StringReader : StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml); reader.ReadLine();

Comment: How are you retrieving the values for the nodes for example...<csdb:OutcomeSource>ERP</csdb:OutcomeSource> or <csdb:ArticleNumber>6034967-Sample</csdb:ArticleNumber> (ERP and 6034967-Sample) ? The other question was in XElement body = soap.Descendants(nsSoapenv + "Body").FirstOrDefault(); can i use something like regex to find all nodes with self closing tag and transform into open and end tag (<tag></tag>) ?

Comment: I'm just inserting the entire xml string into the soap.  Then adding the namespace.  Never us REGEX on an xml file.  Regex is for regular expressions and xml is not regular.

Comment: Ok i got it. and that answered my first Question. but this can be done right? change the tags do generate this envelope? maybe not with Regex...

Comment: still coudln't display the entire envelope . I have XElement soap and XElement body. Apeending them will display the desired output. But how can i do this?

Comment: I don't see anything missing.  The receiving xml is not the same as the one you have in the soap.  My code takes the receiving xml and puts it into the soap body.  There is no header because you didn't provide a header so I left it empty.

Comment: Thank soo much for your help once again! There's only 2 differences that i see when i run your code the generated SOAP XML is: First difference- it generates <csdb:Forecast/> as an example of a self enclosing tag  if there's no value in the node, and it should be <csdb:Forecast></csdb:Forecast>.(THis one is a big issue since in the envelope in the SOAP request i will need to have start and end tag. The last difference is that xmlns:csdb="http://site.de/csdb" goes inside <csdb:VA_002_CreateArticle  xmlns:csdb="http://site.de/csdb"> and it should be inside <soapenv:Envelope tag only. Got me?

Comment: The 1st issue with Forecast isn't an issue.  The two statements are equivalent according to the xml specification.  <csdb:Forecast/> has both a start and end tag together which is allowable.  The definition for csdb I copied from you sample.  As long a csdb is defined before it is used I don't think it matters where it is defined.  So my method should work.  If there is an issue I can easily add it to the VA_002_CreateArticle element.

Comment: When i said <csdb:Forecast/> it was just an example, i meant all the self-closing tags. The thing is when i call the webservices through SOAP UI if i remove the end tag and transform it in a self-closing one, and do the request i get an error!, A generic one, it doesnt even reach the endpoint, thats the problem maybe a question of HTML versions?. About the namespace i guess you are right, i will try to test it as it is. But i believe the self-closing tags are in fact an issue

Comment: With all this said i know those 2 statements are equivalent according to XML standards but i dont if we can say the same in the XML Soap request... the envelope. There's "?" Sometimes in the Soap requests

Comment: Xml specification says the element name in the closing tag is optional.  You can verify the cause of the error by using VS menu : Project : Add New Item : Xml File.  Then paste you xml into the view.  Errors will show in the Error List like any compiler error.  The question marks in the request are part of the query parameters  (like query for a particular date instead of all dates).  I is possible the server is sending responses that do no meet the schema.  Or you are missing a schema declaration.  Your schema declaration is not valid : xmlns:csdb="http://site.de/csdb"

Comment: But you are saying that i shouldn't worry that when i invoke this service at the endpoint in SOAP UI the request appears with begin and end tag, and when i will send this generated code as the envelope it will be with self-closing tags right?.Anyways following your logic i have no other way to change the self closing tag to the start and end tag right? because you are loading the entire xml body just adding the name space prefix.

Comment: Lets not make any assumptions.  Lets find out the what is causing the error.  We need to use a Xml Validation tools to find out what is the root cause of the issue.  My suspicion is the schema requires a value and you do not have have a value.  The format of the closing tag whether it contains the element name or it doesn't contain the element name I do not think has anything to do with the error.

Comment: i am still waiting to receive a valid XML tto give it a proper testing , but still, i have been trying to replace inside that foreach, each Xelement child, something like:  child.Name = nsCsdb.GetName(child.Name.LocalName);
  child.ReplaceWith(new XElement(child.Name, child.Value)); and it would create the proper start and closing tag but i am getting a nullreferenceException

Comment: i think i found a workaround if this won't work i managed to Remove every single Empty node. So just the nodes with value are going in the request. i will test and i will let u know. Thank you so much

Comment: You will not need a work around once you get a valid xml.  It looks like the xml you provided did not meet the schema requirements.

Comment: i will add a new reply to expose the problem. It seems that i need a workaround.

Comment: It works! but i needed some changes, i had to remove the empty nodes otherwise i would get a Zero BigInteger error. thanks!! i can't upvote your answear but you helped a lot!